# Linux Bash Script Ps result is NOT Expected

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I have a script like that :

```
#!/bin/bash

RETVAL=$(ps -ef|  grep -v color | grep opscenter)

echo $RETVAL


if [ "$RETVAL" = "" ];
then
    echo 'Opscenter is NOT running.'
    ./root/opscenter_install/opscenter-6.8.16/bin/opscenter
else
    echo 'Opscenter is running'
    exit 1
fi


exit 0
```

When I run this command on OS , the result is empty :

`ps -ef|  grep -v color | grep opscenter`

When I run this sh , the retval result is like that :

`root 27834 24318 0 12:47 pts/1 00:00:00 sh opscentercheck.sh  root 27835 27834 0 12:47 pts/1 00:00:00 sh opscentercheck.sh  root 27838 27835 0 12:47 pts/1 00:00:00 grep opscenter`

How could I solve this problem ?

Thank you

Result should be `Opscenter is NOT running.`

Thank you.

Comment: Before trying to solve this with `ps`, I recommend checking whether `opscenter` generates a pid-file and use that to check.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably using `grep -v color` because you have an alias like `alias grep='grep --color=auto'`. When you're running a script, your aliases are not present. You could

- use `grep -v grep`
- use `ps -ef | grep '[o]pscenter'` which makes the pattern not match the string so the "grep" command will not be matched.

Now, avoiding the script matching:

- use `ps -ef | grep '[o]pscenter | grep -Fv 'opscenter.sh'` to filter out the script
- use `pgrep opscenter` which searches for the *process* matching "opscenter", not the full command line. This would not match "sh opscenter.sh" because "sh" does not match the pattern "opscenter"